# Issue with Self-signed certificate with Cert-Manager in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, ssl-certificate, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks, cert-manager

I'm trying to add a self-signed certificate in my AKS cluster using Cert-Manager.

I created a `ClusterIssuer` for the CA certificate (to sign the certificate) and a second `ClusterIssuer` for the Certificate (self-signed) I want to use.

I am not sure if the `certificate2` is being used correctly by Ingress as it looks like it is waiting for some event.

Am I following the correct way to do this?

This is the first `ClusterIssuer` "clusterissuer.yml":

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: selfsigned
spec:
  selfSigned: {}
```

This is the CA certificate "certificate.yml":

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: selfsigned-certificate
spec:
  secretName: hello-deployment-tls-ca-key-pair
  dnsNames:
  - "*.default.svc.cluster.local"
  - "*.default.com"
  isCA: true
  issuerRef:
    name: selfsigned
    kind: ClusterIssuer
```

This is the second `ClusterIssuer` "clusterissuer2.yml" for the certificate I want to use:

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
 name: hello-deployment-tls
spec:
 ca:
   secretName: hello-deployment-tls-ca-key-pair
```

and finally this is the self-signed certificate "certificate2.yml":

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: selfsigned-certificate2
spec:
  secretName: hello-deployment-tls-ca-key-pair2
  dnsNames:
  - "*.default.svc.cluster.local"
  - "*.default.com"
  isCA: false
  issuerRef:
    name: hello-deployment-tls
    kind: ClusterIssuer
```

I am using this certificate in an Ingress:

```
--- 
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata: 
  annotations: 
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "hello-deployment-tls"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
  name: sonar-ingress
spec: 
  tls: 
  - secretName: "hello-deployment-tls-ca-key-pair2"
  rules: 
  - http: 
      paths: 
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: "/"
        backend: 
          serviceName: sonarqube
          servicePort: 80
```

As I do not have any registered domain name I just want to use the public IP to access the service over `https://<Public_IP>`.

When I access to the service `https://<Public_IP>` I can see that "Kubernetes Ingress Controller Fake Certificate" so i guess this is because the certificate is not globally recognize by the browser.

The strange thing is here. Theoretically the Ingress deployment is using the `selfsigned-certificate2` but looks like it is not ready:

```
kubectl get certificate
NAME                      READY   SECRET                              AGE
selfsigned-certificate    True    hello-deployment-tls-ca-key-pair    4h29m
selfsigned-certificate2   False   hello-deployment-tls-ca-key-pair2   3h3m
selfsigned-secret         True    selfsigned-secret                   5h25m
```

```
kubectl describe certificate selfsigned-certificate2
. 
.
.
Spec:
  Dns Names:
    *.default.svc.cluster.local
    *.default.com
  Issuer Ref:
    Kind:       ClusterIssuer
    Name:       hello-deployment-tls
  Secret Name:  hello-deployment-tls-ca-key-pair2
Status:
  Conditions:
    Last Transition Time:  2021-10-15T11:16:15Z
    Message:               Waiting for CertificateRequest "selfsigned-certificate2-3983093525" to complete
    Reason:                InProgress
    Status:                False
    Type:                  Ready
Events:                    <none>
```

Any idea?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Any idea here? Thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### ApiVersions

First I noticed you're using `v1alpha2` apiVersion which is depricated and will be removed in `1.6` cert-manager:

```
$ kubectl apply -f cluster-alpha.yaml
Warning: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2 ClusterIssuer is deprecated in v1.4+, unavailable in v1.6+; use cert-manager.io/v1 ClusterIssuer
```

I used `apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1` in reproduction.

Same for `v1beta1` ingress, consider updating it to `networking.k8s.io/v1`.

### What happens

I started reproducing your setup step by step.

I applied `clusterissuer.yaml`:

```
$ kubectl apply -f clusterissuer.yaml
clusterissuer.cert-manager.io/selfsigned created

$ kubectl get clusterissuer
NAME         READY   AGE
selfsigned   True    11s
```

Pay attention that `READY` is set to `True`.

**Next** I applied `certificate.yaml`:

```
$ kubectl apply -f cert.yaml
certificate.cert-manager.io/selfsigned-certificate created

$ kubectl get cert
NAME                     READY   SECRET                             AGE
selfsigned-certificate   True    hello-deployment-tls-ca-key-pair   7s
```

**Next step** is to add the second `ClusterIssuer` which is referenced to `hello-deployment-tls-ca-key-pair` secret:

```
$ kubectl apply -f clusterissuer2.yaml
clusterissuer.cert-manager.io/hello-deployment-tls created

$ kubectl get clusterissuer
NAME                   READY   AGE
hello-deployment-tls   False   6s
selfsigned             True    3m50
```

ClusterIssuer `hello-deployment-tls` is **not** ready. Here's why:

```
$ kubectl describe clusterissuer hello-deployment-tls
...
Events:
  Type     Reason         Age                From          Message
  ----     ------         ----               ----          -------
  Warning  ErrGetKeyPair  10s (x5 over 75s)  cert-manager  Error getting keypair for CA issuer: secret "hello-deployment-tls-ca-key-pair" not found
  Warning  ErrInitIssuer  10s (x5 over 75s)  cert-manager  Error initializing issuer: secret "hello-deployment-tls-ca-key-pair" not found
```

This is expected behaviour since:

> When referencing a Secret resource in ClusterIssuer resources (eg
> apiKeySecretRef) the Secret needs to be in the same namespace as the
> cert-manager controller pod. You can optionally override this by using
> the --cluster-resource-namespace argument to the controller.

[Reference](https://docs.cert-manager.io/en/release-0.11/reference/clusterissuers.html)

### Answer - how to move forward

I edited the `cert-manager` deployment so it will look for `secrets` in `default` namespace (this is not ideal, I'd use `issuer` instead in `default` namespace):

```
$ kubectl edit deploy cert-manager -n cert-manager

spec:
  containers:
  - args:
    - --v=2
    - --cluster-resource-namespace=default
```

It takes about a minute for `cert-manager` to start. Redeployed `clusterissuer2.yaml`:

```
$ kubectl delete -f clusterissuer2.yaml
clusterissuer.cert-manager.io "hello-deployment-tls" deleted

$ kubectl apply -f clusterissuer2.yaml
clusterissuer.cert-manager.io/hello-deployment-tls created

$ kubectl get clusterissuer
NAME                   READY   AGE
hello-deployment-tls   True    3s
selfsigned             True    5m42s
```

Both are `READY`. Moving forward with `certificate2.yaml`:

```
$ kubectl apply -f cert2.yaml
certificate.cert-manager.io/selfsigned-certificate2 created

$ kubectl get cert
NAME                      READY   SECRET                              AGE
selfsigned-certificate    True    hello-deployment-tls-ca-key-pair    33s
selfsigned-certificate2   True    hello-deployment-tls-ca-key-pair2   6s

$ kubectl get certificaterequest
NAME                            APPROVED   DENIED   READY   ISSUER                 REQUESTOR                                         AGE
selfsigned-certificate-jj98f    True                True    selfsigned             system:serviceaccount:cert-manager:cert-manager   52s
selfsigned-certificate2-jwq5c   True                True    hello-deployment-tls   system:serviceaccount:cert-manager:cert-manager   25s
```

### Ingress

When `host` is not added to `ingress`, it doesn't create any certificates and seems to used some fake one from `ingress` which is issued by `CN = Kubernetes Ingress Controller Fake Certificate`.

Events from `ingress`:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age   From                      Message
  ----     ------     ----  ----                      -------
  Warning  BadConfig  5s    cert-manager              TLS entry 0 is invalid: secret "example-cert" for ingress TLS has no hosts specified
```

When I added DNS to `ingress`:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason             Age                From                      Message
  ----     ------             ----               ----                      -------
Normal   CreateCertificate  4s                 cert-manager              Successfully created Certificate "example-cert"
```

### Answer, part 2 (about ingress, certificates and issuer)

You don't need to create a certificate if you're referencing to `issuer` in `ingress` rule. Ingress will issue certificate for you when all details are presented, such as:

- annotation `cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "hello-deployment-tls"`
- `spec.tls` part with host within
- `spec.rules.host`

**OR**

if you want to create certificate manually and ask ingress to use it, then:

- remove annotation `cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "hello-deployment-tls"`
- create certificate manually
- refer to it in `ingress rule`.

You can check certificate details in browser and find that it no longer has issuer as `CN = Kubernetes Ingress Controller Fake Certificate`, in my case it's empty.

### Note - cert-manager v1.4

Initially I used a bit outdated `cert-manager v1.4` and got [this issue](https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/issues/4142) which has gone after updating to `1.4.1`.

It looks like:

```
$ kubectl describe certificaterequest selfsigned-certificate2-45k2c

Events:
  Type     Reason           Age   From          Message
  ----     ------           ----  ----          -------
  Normal   cert-manager.io  41s   cert-manager  Certificate request has been approved by cert-manager.io
  Warning  DecodeError      41s   cert-manager  Failed to decode returned certificate: error decoding certificate PEM block
```

### Useful links:

- [Setting up self-singed Issuer](https://docs.cert-manager.io/en/release-0.11/tasks/issuers/setup-selfsigned.html)
- [Setting up CA issuers](https://docs.cert-manager.io/en/release-0.11/tasks/issuers/setup-ca.html)
- [Cluster Issuers](https://docs.cert-manager.io/en/release-0.11/reference/clusterissuers.html)

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. I'll go through all the info and let you know!

Comment: @Wytrzymały Wiktor really appreciated your time on this. Answer is very well detailed and it worked as a charm! Thx!

Comment: @moonkotte When you mentioned manually creating the certificate and ask ingress to use it. When you say in your last bullet point, refer to it in `ingress rule`. Can you explain where exactly? Do you mean in the `tls[].hosts.secretName`?

Comment: @ByronMansfield Yes, you're correct. It's actually the only possible place to reference it. At this point it's better try to figure out by hands.